# Rubymine cant change Language Level | Updated to Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine, ruby-2.1

I am using `Rubymine 5.4` and just updated to `Ruby 2.1.1`.

I changed the Ruby SDK (Settings/Ruby SDK and Gems) but the Language level is at 1.8 and i cant change it.

[image]

now all my files got error'd out like

`action: 'Show'` isn't accepted anymore with the error message `Expected: ; or end of line`.
I have to change it to `:action => "Show"` to pass validation.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid what you're missing is RubyMine 6! RM5 was written before Ruby 2.1 came out, so it is not compatible with it. I experienced the same problem as you are, so I upgraded to the latest version, and now my language version is 2.1.

Comment: RubyMine 6,7,8 all have the same issue.

Comment: How to change the language level?

Comment: In RubyMine Preferences, go to Language & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems, then there is a dropdown showing Language level. From there you can pick your version which as of Sep 2016 is at 2.3

Comment: @SethJeffery I have Rubymine 6.3 , language level is set to 1.8 and I can't change it.